# Can't join 2 vertices

Tags: vertices

I tried all day to connect those 2 points but I can't for some reason. I keep pressing `F` but it doesn't work. I tried `ctrl+J`, didn't work

[image]

Comment: Just press J - don't  need ctrl. Also, it's hard to tell from your photo, but if you're trying to bisect a face, you could also try the  knife tool (K).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit multiple meshes in edit mode since Blender version 2.80 and the operation you are trying to perform is for a single mesh. Make sure it's a single mesh. Go into object mode and join the meshes if they are separate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: Yeah but how. I tried to press ```ctrl + J``` But it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry my bad - I accidentally typed 'edit' when I meant you should go into object mode. You have to select both objects in object mode, so use tab hotkey to go into object mode and then make sure both objects are selected and one of them is the active object before hitting ctrl + j.

Comment: Yh it didn't work. Idk why. It is super frustrating ngl

Comment: Without you sharing the file it's impossible to know what is going on when you try. Could you share the file?

Comment: omg thanks. I did it. You are supposed to select both objects. Then press ctrl+j. Then go to edit mode. Then select the vertices u want to join and press F

Comment: OK then. Glad it worked.